# Opening External Programs using Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to open a new DevCPP file here. But I want to open it from Java itself and not having to go click on "New" in DevCPP.

This is what I've tried using Runtime object

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
String[] s = new String[] {"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Dev-Cpp\\devcpp.exe"};
try {
    runtime.exec(s); 
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

I want to open the devcpp.exe to a page where a new File has been created
The above program works fine for opening Dev but does not create a new file by itself.
P.S : Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to open notepad for an existing file ?

Comment: I'm glad I could help you. :) Do you mind voting up my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I don't have DevCpp installed (no admin rights on my PC), this should do the trick:

```java
String[] s = new String[] {"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Dev-Cpp\\devcpp.exe", "new_file.cpp"};
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to open notepad for an already existing file using java program, then the command will be like this.

> notepad

An example is given below.

```
notepad C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Temp-Movies.txt
```

Use the above as command in the java program.

Before executing java program, first run using command prompt.

Comment: Thank you for your answer . Though that is not exactly what my question meant .